# Unexpected output for simple code involving calculating a time interval of 10ms

Tags: programming, c++

I had written some code that involved doing something after 10 milliseconds had elapsed, however it was performing unexpectedly. Upon debugging, I think I have identified the error, and I wrote some code with *just* that block:

```
unsigned long int newtime=0;
unsigned long int prevtime=0;
int time;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
newtime=millis();
time=newtime-prevtime;
if(time==10){
  Serial.println(prevtime);
  prevtime+=10;
}
    
}
```

The serial monitor "freezes on 150. it shows the values 0,10,20...as expected but it freezes on 150...and then nothing happens.

What exactly is causing this?

Comment: You should not relay on that if statement to be called once ever millisecond. Check for >= instead

Comment: i didnt properly understand your first comment...

Comment: In my original program, I was doing something when exactly 10 milliseconds had elapsed..

Comment: Your sketch requires that the if statement is called ever millisecond. If `time`is 9 in one iteration and `11` in the next iteration, then the code in the if block will never be executed.

Comment: "when exactly 10 milliseconds" - you can't do it this way, you have to check if *at leaest* 10 ms have elapsed. If you need exact timing you have to use interrupts.

Comment: 10 not 1. and also, since i am resetting the value of prevtime, the value of the variable time cannot exceed 10

Comment: I would say with a frequency of every 10ms you fill up the Serial buffer pretty fast. You could try using a higher baudrate (for example 115200)

Comment: just to add on, the code works perfectly fine when I replace 10 with 100.

Comment: If (for whatever reason) your loop takes *slightly* more than 1 millisecond, then there is a chance that the if statement misses the moment when `time==10` and the if clause will never become true. At least not before millis() ran over.

Comment: @chrisl You are right...it works with that baud rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are filling up the Serial buffer rather fast, because you try to send ASCII numbers every 10ms at only 9600ms. When the buffer is full, `Serial.println()` will wait, until there is enough space free in the buffer for the current data. That makes your loop lasting significantly longer.

In that case the time, where the `time` is exactly 10 is missed. Thus the code does nothing at that point, until time rolls over and gets 10 again (48 days I think).

While you can mitigate the problem by using a higher baudrate, the main problem is still

```
if(time==10){
```

You have only provided an example code. Your real code might sometimes take longer than 10ms out of some other reason (actually this already gets critical, when the loop takes longer than 1ms, since it then might already miss the one moment, where `time` is 10). To futureproof your code and make sure, that you don't hunt down the same bug again and again, you should do, what you were told in the comments, and use

```
if(time>=10){
```

Depending on your code the event will still happen after 10ms the absolute most of the time. But this variant also doesn't break, if the loop takes longer than 10ms sometimes.

Comment: "*might sometimes take longer than 10ms*" - actually the `if(time==10)` version becomes critical as soon as `loop()` takes longer than **1** ms, because it has to compare `time` with ever tick of `millis()` ;)

Comment: @SimSon You are totally right. I will add that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

your logic is just tricky to confuse. It is repeatable because along as you not change the if logic, the code is going to run till it displays 150. then it will stop. You can also check the same behaviour [here](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/297224412670722569)

Once the time difference is not exactly equal to 10, the if part will not be executed. Hence, the `prevtime` will not catch up with the `newtime` anymore. newTime will soon grow to be bigger and the difference will always be greater than 10.

I suggest visiting https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay to get some hints on tracking time in a safer way.